# UserControllerTest is not progressing because of permission errors. Help me

Tags: authentication, security, testing, junit5, mockmvc

I'm Korean, and I'm using a translator, so I'm not sure if the delivery will work.
I'm still a student, so there are so many things I don't know.
Are you working on a team project right now?
I was tasked with testing the admin page.
However, since yesterday, I've been watching all day until dawn, but I can't work because I can't solve it.
I keep trying with the help of ChatGPT but it doesn't work..
I hope you can help me.

Put a User object with role = "ADMIN" in UserDetails,
They say they are trying to get security certification,
No permission to continue. An error occurred...

Modify the AdminController,
I also modified the UserService code, but
I'm not getting an answer...
How can I pass permission and test?

this error code.

```
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.11)

2023-05-05 20:21:38.464  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] s.m.r.c.AdminControllerUnitTest          : Starting AdminControllerUnitTest using Java 11.0.2 on DESKTOP-CNK0AGN with PID 34484 (started by 8491389 in C:\OneDrive - 84913\OneDrive\study material\workspace\1.FINAL_PROJECT\TEAM_TOY_ORIGIN\MiniProject-BE)
2023-05-05 20:21:38.465 DEBUG 34484 --- [    Test worker] s.m.r.c.AdminControllerUnitTest          : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.11, Spring v5.3.27
2023-05-05 20:21:38.466  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] s.m.r.c.AdminControllerUnitTest          : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2023-05-05 20:21:39.850  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@46c662f2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4afdfc0f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@33ebe4f0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5b3518e1, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@10b67f54, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@eded048, shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.jwt.MyJwtAuthorizationFilter@30798137, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5f45bc8e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@33e50ff2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@455da438, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7b451bf4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@d84418a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2dc21583]
2023-05-05 20:21:40.521  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2023-05-05 20:21:40.522  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2023-05-05 20:21:40.523  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-05-05 20:21:40.555  INFO 34484 --- [    Test worker] s.m.r.c.AdminControllerUnitTest          : Started AdminControllerUnitTest in 2.49 seconds (JVM running for 4.169)

class shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.Authentication (shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails and org.springframework.security.core.Authentication are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.Authentication (shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails and org.springframework.security.core.Authentication are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at shop.mtcoding.restend.controller.AdminControllerUnitTest.testAnnualUpdate(AdminControllerUnitTest.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


AdminControllerUnitTest > testAnnualUpdate() FAILED
    java.lang.ClassCastException at AdminControllerUnitTest.java:90
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/OneDrive%20-%2084913/OneDrive/study%20material/workspace/1.FINAL_PROJECT/TEAM_TOY_ORIGIN/MiniProject-BE/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

this AdminControllerUnitTest code.

```
package shop.mtcoding.restend.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.MyWithMockUser;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.advice.MyLogAdvice;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.advice.MyValidAdvice;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.config.MyFilterRegisterConfig;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.config.MySecurityConfig;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.dummy.DummyEntity;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.ResponseDTO;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.manage.Manage;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.model.user.User;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;




@WebMvcTest(controllers = AdminController.class)
@Import({MySecurityConfig.class, MyFilterRegisterConfig.class})
public class AdminControllerUnitTest extends DummyEntity{


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    User user = newMockUser(1L,"cos", "코스","ADMIN",2);
    private MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails(user);

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void testAnnualUpdate() throws Exception{
        // given
        Long id = 1L;
        User userPS = User.builder().id(id).remain_days(5).build();

        Manage manage = new Manage().toEntityOut(userPS);

        when(userService.annualUpdate(Mockito.any(Long.class), any(Manage.AnnualRequestDTO.class)))
                .thenReturn(manage);

        // 설정
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication((Authentication) myUserDetails);


        // when
        ResultActions resultActions = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/admin/annual/{id}", id)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               // .content(om.writeValueAsString(manage))
               // .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(myUserDetails))
        );

        String responseBody = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println("테스트 : "+ responseBody);

        // then
        resultActions.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.msg").value("success"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data").exists())
                .andReturn();
    }

}
```

this AdminController code.

```
package shop.mtcoding.restend.controller;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.exception.Exception403;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.ResponseDTO;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.manage.Manage;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.service.UserService;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class AdminController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final HttpSession session;

    // 회원 정보 변경 로직
    @PostMapping("/admin/annual/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> annualUpdate(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Manage.AnnualRequestDTO annualRequestDTO, @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails) {
        // 1. 권한 확인
        if ("USER".equals(myUserDetails.getUser().getRole())) {
        throw new Exception403("권한이 없습니다.");
        }
            // 2. 바꾸려는 회원정보가 있는지 확인 후 회원 정보 업데이트
            Manage managePS = userService.연차수정(id, annualRequestDTO);
            ResponseDTO<?>responseDTO = new ResponseDTO<>(managePS);
            // 3. 변경된 정보를 앞단에 건네준다.
            //checkpoint : 받은 데이터를 그래도 돌려줘야하나? 아니면 User객체로 건네주어야하나
            // 아니면, 회원 관리 페이지를 통째로 줘야하나, 아니면 리다이렉션 해야되나..
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseDTO);

    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> userChart(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int page,@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails) {
        // 1. 권한 확인
        if ("MASTER".equals(myUserDetails.getUser().getRole()) || "ADMIN".equals(myUserDetails.getUser().getRole())) {
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, 10, Sort.by("id").descending());
        Page<Manage.UserManageDTO> userListPS = userService.회원목록보기(pageRequest);
        ResponseDTO<Page> responseDTO = new ResponseDTO<>(userListPS);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseDTO);
    }
        throw new Exception403("권한이 없습니다.");
    }

    // role까지 변경가능, master로 접근해야, role변경이 가능하다.
    @PostMapping("/admin/role/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> userUpdate(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody Manage.MasterDTO masterDTO, @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails){
        if(!"MASTER".equals(myUserDetails.getUser().getRole())){
            throw new Exception403("권한이 없습니다.");
        }
        Manage.MasterDTO masterOut = userService.권한수정(id,masterDTO);
        ResponseDTO<?>responseDTO = new ResponseDTO<>(HttpStatus.OK,"success",masterOut);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseDTO);
    }
}
```

this UserService code.

```
package shop.mtcoding.restend.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.annotation.MyLog;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.jwt.MyJwtProvider;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.auth.session.MyUserDetails;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.exception.Exception400;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.exception.Exception401;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.core.exception.Exception500;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.manage.Manage;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.user.UserRequest;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.dto.user.UserResponse;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.model.user.User;
import shop.mtcoding.restend.model.user.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    
    @MyLog
    @Transactional
    public Manage annualUpdate(Long id, Manage.AnnualRequestDTO annualRequestDTO) {
        Manage manage = new Manage();
        User userPS = userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()->new Exception400("id", "해당 유저가 존재하지 않습니다"));
        // 정보 수정
        Manage.AnnualRequestDTO managePS = new Manage.AnnualRequestDTO(annualRequestDTO.getRemain_days());
        userPS.update(managePS.toEntityIn());
        return manage.toEntityOut(userPS);
    } 
}
```

By passing permission in the annualUpdate method,
I want to safely receive the 200 status code in the andExpect() method.

https://github.com/MiniTeam-5/MiniProject-BE/tree/feature/manage

This is our team's flag address.
feature/manage is the branch I'm working on.